# Yosemite Regularly Crashes, Returns to Login Screen

Tags: macos, finder, crash

I have a Macbook Pro 6,2 (mid-2010 model) with Yosemite installed. Recently, my computer has started crashing in a number of ways. First of all, it often crashes and bumps me back to the login screen (which normally is disabled, as I'm the only user of my computer and I just have it start up on its own). This seems to happen most frequently while using Firefox, but also happens occasionally at other times. Firefox also often crashes (without the computer's crashing), and every so often Google Chrome crashes too.

I've also been getting assertion failed errors with Finder. This is the log from Console from the kernel panic I just had a moment ago:

`5/21/15 11:30:56.158 PM Finder[248]: assertion failed: 14D136: libxpc.dylib + 62495 [D35D0DB2-D7BD-3BE4-8378-062BFE545E1D]: 0x89`

It also just crashed to the login screen at 11:18 PM and 11:27 PM. Does anyone know what causes this - or how to resolve it?

Here are the console log from the latest crash:

```
5/21/15 11:27:15.000 PM kernel[0]: Data/Stack execution not permitted: WindowServer[pid 884] at virtual address 0x7fff52888000, protections were read-write
5/21/15 11:27:15.129 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.ReportCrash.Root[1112]) Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.ReportCrash.DirectoryService
5/21/15 11:27:16.931 PM hidd[97]: IOHIDEventQueue unable to get policy for event of type 11. (e00002e8)
5/21/15 11:27:16.937 PM hidd[97]: IOHIDEventQueue unable to get policy for event of type 11. (e00002e8)
5/21/15 11:27:16.945 PM hidd[97]: IOHIDEventQueue unable to get policy for event of type 11. (e00002e8)
5/21/15 11:27:16.953 PM hidd[97]: IOHIDEventQueue unable to get policy for event of type 11. (e00002e8)
5/21/15 11:27:16.961 PM hidd[97]: IOHIDEventQueue unable to get policy for event of type 11. (e00002e8)
5/21/15 11:27:16.969 PM hidd[97]: IOHIDEventQueue unable to get policy for event of type 11. (e00002e8)
5/21/15 11:27:16.977 PM hidd[97]: IOHIDEventQueue unable to get policy for event of type 11. (e00002e8)
5/21/15 11:27:16.987 PM hidd[97]: IOHIDEventQueue unable to get policy for event of type 11. (e00002e8)
5/21/15 11:27:16.993 PM hidd[97]: IOHIDEventQueue unable to get policy for event of type 11. (e00002e8)
5/21/15 11:27:17.001 PM hidd[97]: IOHIDEventQueue unable to get policy for event of type 11. (e00002e8)
5/21/15 11:27:17.009 PM hidd[97]: IOHIDEventQueue unable to get policy for event of type 11. (e00002e8)
5/21/15 11:27:17.019 PM hidd[97]: IOHIDEventQueue unable to get policy for event of type 11. (e00002e8)
5/21/15 11:27:17.025 PM hidd[97]: IOHIDEventQueue unable to get policy for event of type 11. (e00002e8)
5/21/15 11:27:17.033 PM hidd[97]: IOHIDEventQueue unable to get policy for event of type 11. (e00002e8)
5/21/15 11:27:17.041 PM hidd[97]: IOHIDEventQueue unable to get policy for event of type 11. (e00002e8)
5/21/15 11:27:17.049 PM hidd[97]: IOHIDEventQueue unable to get policy for event of type 11. (e00002e8)
5/21/15 11:27:17.057 PM hidd[97]: IOHIDEventQueue unable to get policy for event of type 11. (e00002e8)
5/21/15 11:27:17.065 PM hidd[97]: IOHIDEventQueue unable to get policy for event of type 11. (e00002e8)
5/21/15 11:27:17.073 PM hidd[97]: IOHIDEventQueue unable to get policy for event of type 11. (e00002e8)
5/21/15 11:27:17.089 PM hidd[97]: IOHIDEventQueue unable to get policy for event of type 11. (e00002e8)
5/21/15 11:27:17.113 PM hidd[97]: IOHIDEventQueue unable to get policy for event of type 11. (e00002e8)
5/21/15 11:27:17.121 PM hidd[97]: IOHIDEventQueue unable to get policy for event of type 11. (e00002e8)
5/21/15 11:27:17.129 PM hidd[97]: IOHIDEventQueue unable to get policy for event of type 11. (e00002e8)
5/21/15 11:27:17.137 PM hidd[97]: IOHIDEventQueue unable to get policy for event of type 11. (e00002e8)
5/21/15 11:27:17.145 PM hidd[97]: IOHIDEventQueue unable to get policy for event of type 11. (e00002e8)
5/21/15 11:27:17.153 PM hidd[97]: IOHIDEventQueue unable to get policy for event of type 11. (e00002e8)
5/21/15 11:27:17.161 PM hidd[97]: IOHIDEventQueue unable to get policy for event of type 11. (e00002e8)
5/21/15 11:27:17.169 PM hidd[97]: IOHIDEventQueue unable to get policy for event of type 11. (e00002e8)
5/21/15 11:27:17.177 PM hidd[97]: IOHIDEventQueue unable to get policy for event of type 11. (e00002e8)
5/21/15 11:27:17.249 PM hidd[97]: IOHIDEventQueue unable to get policy for event of type 11. (e00002e8)
5/21/15 11:27:17.281 PM hidd[97]: IOHIDEventQueue unable to get policy for event of type 11. (e00002e8)
5/21/15 11:27:17.415 PM loginwindow[886]: ERROR | -[LoginApp windowServerExited] | Window Server exited, closing down the session immediately
5/21/15 11:27:17.417 PM Evernote[912]: HIToolbox: received notification of WindowServer event port death.
5/21/15 11:27:17.417 PM Spotlight[924]: HIToolbox: received notification of WindowServer event port death.
5/21/15 11:27:17.417 PM Spotlight[924]: port matched the WindowServer port created in BindCGSToRunLoop
5/21/15 11:27:17.417 PM Evernote[912]: port matched the WindowServer port created in BindCGSToRunLoop
5/21/15 11:27:17.417 PM Calendar[913]: HIToolbox: received notification of WindowServer event port death.
5/21/15 11:27:17.418 PM Calendar[913]: port matched the WindowServer port created in BindCGSToRunLoop
5/21/15 11:27:17.419 PM Dock[915]: HIToolbox: received notification of WindowServer event port death.
5/21/15 11:27:17.419 PM Dock[915]: port matched the WindowServer port created in BindCGSToRunLoop
5/21/15 11:27:17.420 PM SystemUIServer[917]: HIToolbox: received notification of WindowServer event port death.
5/21/15 11:27:17.420 PM SystemUIServer[917]: port matched the WindowServer port created in BindCGSToRunLoop
5/21/15 11:27:17.421 PM EvernoteHelper[960]: HIToolbox: received notification of WindowServer event port death.
5/21/15 11:27:17.421 PM EvernoteHelper[960]: port matched the WindowServer port created in BindCGSToRunLoop
5/21/15 11:27:17.421 PM Caffeine[1013]: HIToolbox: received notification of WindowServer event port death.
5/21/15 11:27:17.422 PM AppTrap[1016]: HIToolbox: received notification of WindowServer event port death.
5/21/15 11:27:17.422 PM AppTrap[1016]: port matched the WindowServer port created in BindCGSToRunLoop
5/21/15 11:27:17.423 PM Caffeine[1013]: port matched the WindowServer port created in BindCGSToRunLoop
5/21/15 11:27:17.423 PM NotificationCenter[987]: HIToolbox: received notification of WindowServer event port death.
5/21/15 11:27:17.424 PM NotificationCenter[987]: port matched the WindowServer port created in BindCGSToRunLoop
5/21/15 11:27:17.425 PM plugin-container[953]: HIToolbox: received notification of WindowServer event port death.
5/21/15 11:27:17.425 PM plugin-container[953]: port matched the WindowServer port created in BindCGSToRunLoop
5/21/15 11:27:17.426 PM firefox[910]: HIToolbox: received notification of WindowServer event port death.
5/21/15 11:27:17.426 PM firefox[910]: port matched the WindowServer port created in BindCGSToRunLoop
5/21/15 11:27:17.428 PM garcon[1101]: HIToolbox: received notification of WindowServer event port death.
5/21/15 11:27:17.428 PM garcon[1101]: port matched the WindowServer port created in BindCGSToRunLoop
5/21/15 11:27:17.429 PM CIJScannerRegister[1108]: HIToolbox: received notification of WindowServer event port death.
5/21/15 11:27:17.429 PM CIJScannerRegister[1108]: port matched the WindowServer port created in BindCGSToRunLoop
5/21/15 11:27:17.430 PM com.apple.dock.extra[942]: HIToolbox: received notification of WindowServer event port death.
5/21/15 11:27:17.430 PM Image Capture Extension[1107]: HIToolbox: received notification of WindowServer event port death.
5/21/15 11:27:17.430 PM com.apple.dock.extra[942]: port matched the WindowServer port created in BindCGSToRunLoop
5/21/15 11:27:17.430 PM Image Capture Extension[1107]: port matched the WindowServer port created in BindCGSToRunLoop
5/21/15 11:27:17.431 PM Memory Clean[1033]: HIToolbox: received notification of WindowServer event port death.
5/21/15 11:27:17.431 PM Memory Clean[1033]: port matched the WindowServer port created in BindCGSToRunLoop
5/21/15 11:27:17.432 PM CoreServicesUIAgent[925]: HIToolbox: received notification of WindowServer event port death.
5/21/15 11:27:17.432 PM CoreServicesUIAgent[925]: port matched the WindowServer port created in BindCGSToRunLoop
5/21/15 11:27:17.433 PM pia_tray[1070]: HIToolbox: received notification of WindowServer event port death.
5/21/15 11:27:17.433 PM pia_tray[1070]: port matched the WindowServer port created in BindCGSToRunLoop
5/21/15 11:27:17.433 PM Keychain Circle Notification[984]: HIToolbox: received notification of WindowServer event port death.
5/21/15 11:27:17.433 PM com.github.GitHub.Conduit[993]: HIToolbox: received notification of WindowServer event port death.
5/21/15 11:27:17.433 PM Keychain Circle Notification[984]: port matched the WindowServer port created in BindCGSToRunLoop
5/21/15 11:27:17.434 PM com.github.GitHub.Conduit[993]: port matched the WindowServer port created in BindCGSToRunLoop
5/21/15 11:27:17.435 PM TISwitcher[1014]: HIToolbox: received notification of WindowServer event port death.
5/21/15 11:27:17.435 PM TISwitcher[1014]: port matched the WindowServer port created in BindCGSToRunLoop
5/21/15 11:27:17.436 PM LaterAgent[1081]: HIToolbox: received notification of WindowServer event port death.
5/21/15 11:27:17.436 PM LaterAgent[1081]: port matched the WindowServer port created in BindCGSToRunLoop
5/21/15 11:27:17.437 PM Dropbox[1015]: HIToolbox: received notification of WindowServer event port death.
5/21/15 11:27:17.437 PM Dropbox[1015]: port matched the WindowServer port created in BindCGSToRunLoop
5/21/15 11:27:17.438 PM cloudphotosd[1018]: HIToolbox: received notification of WindowServer event port death.
5/21/15 11:27:17.438 PM Flux[1009]: HIToolbox: received notification of WindowServer event port death.
5/21/15 11:27:17.438 PM cloudphotosd[1018]: port matched the WindowServer port created in BindCGSToRunLoop
5/21/15 11:27:17.438 PM Flux[1009]: port matched the WindowServer port created in BindCGSToRunLoop
5/21/15 11:27:17.439 PM WiFiAgent[1002]: HIToolbox: received notification of WindowServer event port death.
5/21/15 11:27:17.439 PM WiFiAgent[1002]: port matched the WindowServer port created in BindCGSToRunLoop
5/21/15 11:27:17.440 PM Finder[918]: HIToolbox: received notification of WindowServer event port death.
5/21/15 11:27:17.440 PM Finder[918]: port matched the WindowServer port created in BindCGSToRunLoop
5/21/15 11:27:17.440 PM CrashPlan menu bar[1021]: HIToolbox: received notification of WindowServer event port death.
5/21/15 11:27:17.441 PM CrashPlan menu bar[1021]: port matched the WindowServer port created in BindCGSToRunLoop
5/21/15 11:27:17.443 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.WindowServer[884]) Service exited due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11
5/21/15 11:27:17.444 PM Console[971]: CGSGetSurfaceBounds failed - error 268435459 (window:85, surface:849372945
5/21/15 11:27:17.445 PM Console[971]: CGSSetSurfaceShape failed - error 268435459 (window:85, surface:849372945, bounds:{{221, 28}, {16, 604}}
5/21/15 11:27:17.476 PM sessionlogoutd[1113]: sessionlogoutd Launched
5/21/15 11:27:17.523 PM loginwindow[886]: HIToolbox: received notification of WindowServer event port death.
5/21/15 11:27:17.523 PM loginwindow[886]: port matched the WindowServer port created in BindCGSToRunLoop
5/21/15 11:27:17.571 PM Console[971]: CGSGetSurfaceBounds failed - error 268435459 (window:85, surface:849372945
5/21/15 11:27:17.572 PM Console[971]: CGSSetSurfaceShape failed - error 268435459 (window:85, surface:849372945, bounds:{{221, 28}, {16, 604}}
5/21/15 11:27:17.573 PM Console[971]: CGSStructuralRegionSetShape returned CG error 268435459
5/21/15 11:27:17.587 PM Console[971]: HIToolbox: received notification of WindowServer event port death.
5/21/15 11:27:17.587 PM Console[971]: port matched the WindowServer port created in BindCGSToRunLoop
5/21/15 11:27:17.590 PM Console[971]: CGSGetSurfaceBounds failed - error 268435459 (window:85, surface:849372945
5/21/15 11:27:17.590 PM Console[971]: CGSSetSurfaceShape failed - error 268435459 (window:85, surface:849372945, bounds:{{221, 28}, {16, 604}}
5/21/15 11:27:17.802 PM sessionlogoutd[1113]: CGSLookupServerRootPort: Failed to look up the port for "com.apple.windowserver.active" (1102)
5/21/15 11:27:17.803 PM sessionlogoutd[1113]: DEAD_PROCESS: 886 console
5/21/15 11:27:17.807 PM sessionlogoutd[1113]: CGSLookupServerRootPort: Failed to look up the port for "com.apple.windowserver.active" (1102)
5/21/15 11:27:17.808 PM sessionlogoutd[1113]: numberOfConsoleUsers:216: ERROR: CGSCopySessionList returned NULL.
5/21/15 11:27:17.910 PM Console[971]: CGSGetSurfaceBounds failed - error 268435459 (window:85, surface:849372945
5/21/15 11:27:17.910 PM Console[971]: CGSSetSurfaceShape failed - error 268435459 (window:85, surface:849372945, bounds:{{221, 28}, {16, 604}}
5/21/15 11:27:17.912 PM Console[971]: CGSStructuralRegionSetShape returned CG error 268435459
5/21/15 11:27:17.929 PM Flux[1009]: Display list confused, doing full reset.
5/21/15 11:27:18.137 PM ReportCrash[1112]: Saved crash report for WindowServer[884] version 1 to /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/WindowServer_2015-05-21-232718_Brendan-ODonnells-MacBook-Pro.crash
5/21/15 11:27:18.260 PM com.apple.dock.extra[942]: SOHelperCenter main connection interrupted
5/21/15 11:27:18.262 PM sharingd[963]: 23:27:18.262 : SIGTERM received, shutting down.
5/21/15 11:27:18.237 PM garcon[1101]: host connection <NSXPCConnection: 0x60000011fa40> connection from pid 918 invalidated
5/21/15 11:27:18.238 PM identityservicesd[933]: Quit - notifying about shutdown
5/21/15 11:27:18.264 PM identityservicesd[933]: Quit - shutting down daemon
5/21/15 11:27:18.296 PM imagent[928]: Quit - notifying about shutdown
5/21/15 11:27:18.297 PM imagent[928]: Quit - shutting down daemon
5/21/15 11:27:18.266 PM UserEventAgent[39]: Captive: [UserAgentDied:143] User Agent @port=79303 Died
5/21/15 11:27:18.286 PM nsurlsessiond[923]: SIGTERM received, shutting down.
5/21/15 11:27:18.312 PM spindump[422]: Got xpc error message in libspindump client connection: Connection invalid
5/21/15 11:27:18.343 PM com.apple.dock.extra[942]: SOHelperCenter main connection interrupted
5/21/15 11:27:18.424 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.iTunesHelper.122720[1011]) Service exited with abnormal code: 1
5/21/15 11:27:18.521 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.Dock.agent[915]) Service exited with abnormal code: 1
5/21/15 11:27:18.532 PM loginwindow[1115]: Login Window Application Started
5/21/15 11:27:18.581 PM WindowServer[1116]: Server is starting up
5/21/15 11:27:18.847 PM WindowServer[1116]: Session 257 retained (2 references)
5/21/15 11:27:18.847 PM WindowServer[1116]: Session 257 released (1 references)
5/21/15 11:27:18.877 PM WindowServer[1116]: Session 257 retained (2 references)
5/21/15 11:27:18.880 PM WindowServer[1116]: init_page_flip: page flip mode is on
5/21/15 11:27:18.882 PM WindowServer[1116]: Found 1 modes for display 0x00000000 [1, 0]
5/21/15 11:27:18.885 PM WindowServer[1116]: Found 1 modes for display 0x00000000 [1, 0]
5/21/15 11:27:18.891 PM WindowServer[1116]: Found 12 modes for display 0x00000000 [12, 0]
5/21/15 11:27:18.916 PM WindowServer[1116]: mux_initialize: Mode is dynamic
5/21/15 11:27:18.924 PM WindowServer[1116]: Found 12 modes for display 0x00000000 [12, 0]
5/21/15 11:27:18.929 PM WindowServer[1116]: Found 1 modes for display 0x00000000 [1, 0]
5/21/15 11:27:18.945 PM WindowServer[1116]: WSMachineUsesNewStyleMirroring: false
5/21/15 11:27:18.947 PM WindowServer[1116]: Display 0x003f003e: GL mask 0x4; bounds (0, 0)[0 x 0], 1 modes available
off-line, enabled, Vendor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 2, Rotation 0
UUID 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
5/21/15 11:27:18.947 PM WindowServer[1116]: Display 0x042728c1: GL mask 0x3; bounds (0, 0)[1440 x 900], 12 modes available
Main, Active, on-line, enabled, built-in, boot, Vendor 610, Model 9ca3, S/N 0, Unit 1, Rotation 0
UUID 0xe2d0b55c862d4b0eba07e1bd2579493f
5/21/15 11:27:18.947 PM WindowServer[1116]: Set a breakpoint at CGSLogError to catch errors as they are logged.
5/21/15 11:27:18.947 PM WindowServer[1116]: WSSetWindowTransform: Singular matrix
5/21/15 11:27:19.161 PM WindowServer[1116]: Display 0x042728c1: GL mask 0x3; bounds (0, 0)[1440 x 900], 12 modes available
Main, Active, on-line, enabled, built-in, boot, Vendor 610, Model 9ca3, S/N 0, Unit 1, Rotation 0
UUID 0xe2d0b55c862d4b0eba07e1bd2579493f
5/21/15 11:27:19.161 PM WindowServer[1116]: Display 0x003f003e: GL mask 0x4; bounds (2464, 0)[1 x 1], 1 modes available
off-line, enabled, Vendor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 2, Rotation 0
UUID 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
5/21/15 11:27:19.161 PM WindowServer[1116]: CGXPerformInitialDisplayConfiguration
5/21/15 11:27:19.161 PM WindowServer[1116]:   Display 0x042728c1: Unit 1; Alias(0, 0x3); Vendor 0x610 Model 0x9ca3 S/N 0 Dimensions 13.03 x 8.15; online enabled built-in, Bounds (0,0)[1440 x 900], Rotation 0, Resolution 1
5/21/15 11:27:19.162 PM WindowServer[1116]:   Display 0x003f003e: Unit 2; Vendor 0xffffffff Model 0xffffffff S/N -1 Dimensions 0.00 x 0.00; offline enabled, Bounds (2464,0)[1 x 1], Rotation 0, Resolution 1
5/21/15 11:27:19.165 PM WindowServer[1116]: CGXMuxBoot: Boot normal
5/21/15 11:27:19.266 PM WindowServer[1116]: GLCompositor: GL renderer id 0x01024300, GL mask 0x00000001, accelerator 0x00003b9b, unit 0, caps QEX|MIPMAP, vram 288 MB
5/21/15 11:27:19.266 PM WindowServer[1116]: GLCompositor: GL renderer id 0x01024300, GL mask 0x00000001, texture max 8192, viewport max {8192, 8192}, extensions NPOT|GLSL|FLOAT
5/21/15 11:27:19.266 PM WindowServer[1116]: GLCompositor: GL renderer id 0x01022612, GL mask 0x00000006, accelerator 0x00002433, unit 1, caps QEX|MIPMAP, vram 256 MB
5/21/15 11:27:19.640 PM WindowServer[1116]: GLCompositor: GL renderer id 0x01022612, GL mask 0x00000006, texture max 8192, viewport max {8192, 8192}, extensions NPOT|GLSL|FLOAT
5/21/15 11:27:19.640 PM WindowServer[1116]: GLCompositor enabled for tile size [256 x 256]
5/21/15 11:27:19.640 PM WindowServer[1116]: CGXGLInitMipMap: mip map mode is on
5/21/15 11:27:19.706 PM WindowServer[1116]: CGXSetDisplayColorProfileAndTransfer: Display 0x042728c1: Unit 1; ColorProfile { -474710019 }; TransferTable (256, 12)
5/21/15 11:27:19.707 PM com.apple.AmbientDisplayAgent[209]: AMBD Agent: xpc connection became invalid during event handler
5/21/15 11:27:19.713 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.AssistiveControl.running) The HideUntilCheckIn property is an architectural performance issue. Please transition away from it.
5/21/15 11:27:19.713 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.btsa) This key does not do anything: OnDemand
5/21/15 11:27:19.714 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.coreservices.lsactivity) Unknown key for Boolean: DrainMessagesAfterFailedInit
5/21/15 11:27:19.717 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.helpd) This key does not do anything: OnDemand
5/21/15 11:27:19.725 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.noticeboard.agent) This key does not do anything: OnDemand
5/21/15 11:27:19.731 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.speech.speechsynthesisd) This key does not do anything: OnDemand
5/21/15 11:27:19.733 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.inputswitcher.running) The HideUntilCheckIn property is an architectural performance issue. Please transition away from it.
5/21/15 11:27:19.733 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.universalaccesscontrol.running) The HideUntilCheckIn property is an architectural performance issue. Please transition away from it.
5/21/15 11:27:19.733 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.universalaccessd.running) The HideUntilCheckIn property is an architectural performance issue. Please transition away from it.
5/21/15 11:27:19.735 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.UserEventAgent-LoginWindow) This service is defined to be constantly running and is inherently inefficient.
5/21/15 11:27:19.736 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.VoiceOver.running) The HideUntilCheckIn property is an architectural performance issue. Please transition away from it.
5/21/15 11:27:19.738 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.ZoomWindow.running) The HideUntilCheckIn property is an architectural performance issue. Please transition away from it.
5/21/15 11:27:19.883 PM ReportCrash[1112]: Saved crash report for plugin-container[953] version 1.0 to /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/plugin-container_2015-05-21-232719_Brendan-ODonnells-MacBook-Pro.crash
5/21/15 11:27:19.926 PM PowerChime[1122]: objc[1122]: Class BUIPowerSource is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BatteryUIKit.framework/Versions/A/BatteryUIKit and /System/Library/CoreServices/PowerChime.app/Contents/MacOS/PowerChime. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
5/21/15 11:27:20.167 PM askpermissiond[1118]: objc[1118]: Class FALogging is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FamilyCircle.framework/Versions/A/FamilyCircle and /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FamilyNotification.framework/Versions/A/FamilyNotification. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
5/21/15 11:27:20.189 PM askpermissiond[1118]: StoreTransport: Resetting APS Connection using environment name production
5/21/15 11:27:20.215 PM com.apple.SecurityServer[80]: Session 100043 created
5/21/15 11:27:20.300 PM com.apple.internetaccounts[290]: [Warning] Failed IMDRequestPortConnection, no reply
5/21/15 11:27:20.301 PM com.apple.internetaccounts[290]: [Warning] IMLocalObject: Could not create server for listener: <IMDaemonListener: 0x6000002e0700>
5/21/15 11:27:20.301 PM com.apple.internetaccounts[290]: [Warning] Failed to launch and connect to daemon
5/21/15 11:27:20.301 PM com.apple.internetaccounts[290]: [Warning] Failed to launch and connect to daemon
5/21/15 11:27:20.683 PM loginwindow[1115]: Setting the initial value of the magsave brightness level 1
5/21/15 11:27:20.757 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.DataDetectorsDynamicData) The JoinExistingSession key is only available to Application services.
5/21/15 11:27:20.758 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.appkit.xpc.sandboxedServiceRunner) The JoinExistingSession key is only available to Application services.
5/21/15 11:27:20.773 PM loginwindow[1115]: Login Window Started Security Agent
5/21/15 11:27:20.950 PM WindowServer[1116]: **DMPROXY** (2) Found `/System/Library/CoreServices/DMProxy'. Run with arg = -discovery
5/21/15 11:27:21.017 PM WindowServer[1116]: CGXSetDisplayColorProfileAndTransfer: Display 0x042728c1: Unit 1; ColorProfile { -474710019 }; TransferTable (256, 12)
5/21/15 11:27:21.024 PM com.apple.AmbientDisplayAgent[209]: AMBD Agent: xpc connection became invalid during event handler
5/21/15 11:27:21.037 PM WiFiAgent[1125]:  securityd_message_with_reply_sync Failed to talk to secd after 4 attempts.
5/21/15 11:27:21.099 PM DMProxy[1129]: AMBD Services: connection interrupted: com.apple.AmbientDisplayAgent (Connection interrupted)
5/21/15 11:27:21.110 PM com.apple.AmbientDisplayAgent[209]: AmbientDisplayAgent started
5/21/15 11:27:21.139 PM com.apple.AmbientDisplayAgent[209]: AMBD initializing devices
5/21/15 11:27:21.166 PM WindowServer[1116]: CGXSetDisplayColorProfileAndTransfer: Display 0x042728c1: Unit 1; ColorProfile { -474710019 }; TransferTable (256, 12)
5/21/15 11:27:21.168 PM com.apple.AmbientDisplayAgent[209]: AMBD Agent: xpc connection became invalid during event handler
5/21/15 11:27:21.228 PM UserEventAgent[1124]: Failed to copy info dictionary for bundle /System/Library/UserEventPlugins/alfUIplugin.plugin
5/21/15 11:27:21.245 PM SecurityAgent[1128]: MacBuddy was run = 0
5/21/15 11:27:21.440 PM WindowServer[1116]: _CGXGLDisplayContextForDisplayDevice: acquired display context (0x7f80086008c0) - enabling OpenGL
5/21/15 11:27:21.713 PM UserEventAgent[1124]: user agent networkd: built Feb 12 2015 17:21:33
5/21/15 11:27:22.493 PM com.apple.internetaccounts[290]: [Warning] Failed IMDRequestPortConnection, no reply
5/21/15 11:27:22.493 PM com.apple.internetaccounts[290]: [Warning] IMLocalObject: Could not create server for listener: <IMDaemonListener: 0x6000002e0700>
5/21/15 11:27:22.493 PM com.apple.internetaccounts[290]: [Warning] Failed to launch and connect to daemon
5/21/15 11:27:22.494 PM com.apple.internetaccounts[290]: [Warning] Failed to launch and connect to daemon
5/21/15 11:27:23.230 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (org.herf.Flux.83244[1009]) Service did not exit 5 seconds after SIGTERM. Sending SIGKILL.
5/21/15 11:27:23.468 PM com.apple.iCloudHelper[947]: ***storageTaskManagerExistsWithIdentifier:withIdentifier failed: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "Couldn’t communicate with a helper application." (The connection to service named com.apple.nsurlstorage-cache was invalidated.) UserInfo=0x7fb4c0446690 {NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.nsurlstorage-cache was invalidated.}; {
    NSDebugDescription = "The connection to service named com.apple.nsurlstorage-cache was invalidated.";
}
5/21/15 11:27:24.690 PM com.apple.internetaccounts[290]: [Warning] Failed IMDRequestPortConnection, no reply
5/21/15 11:27:24.690 PM com.apple.internetaccounts[290]: [Warning] IMLocalObject: Could not create server for listener: <IMDaemonListener: 0x6000002e0700>
5/21/15 11:27:24.691 PM com.apple.internetaccounts[290]: [Warning] Failed to launch and connect to daemon
5/21/15 11:27:24.691 PM com.apple.internetaccounts[290]: [Warning] Failed to launch and connect to daemon
5/21/15 11:27:25.724 PM BezelServices 250.15[1115]: ASSERTION FAILED: dvcAddrRef != ((void *)0) -[DriverServices getDeviceAddress:] line: 2727
5/21/15 11:27:25.724 PM BezelServices 250.15[1115]: ASSERTION FAILED: dvcAddrRef != ((void *)0) -[DriverServices getDeviceAddress:] line: 2727
```

There are a bunch of `Path not allowed in target domain` and `Failed to bootstrap path` errors too that I omitted because this post was too long.

I've run antivirus checks and didn't find anything, and also ran memtest86 to check if it was the memory, which it is not. I also read the previous Stack Exchange answers on similar issues, but I'm not sure what could be causing my problem. Any ideas as to what it could be?

Comment: It is having some sort of Graphics problem, but not sure why?

Comment: Ah, thanks! Thanks to your comment, I looked up graphics problems for Macbook Pro 6,2 computers, and I found this: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5759538?start=0&tstart=0 Looks like it's a known issue where some chips had a Latent Defect. I'll have to take it in the Genius Bar to see if this is the issue I'm dealing with.

Comment: Do you use f.lux? This may be the cause of the problem.

Comment: I do use f.lux. If the Apple store says there's no problem with the logic board, I'll disable it and see if anything comes up. Is there a known issue with f.lux and Yosemite?

Comment: Update on this: It's not f.lux; I disabled it, and the crashes continue. My computer passed the Visual Systems Test, so it's probably still the logic board, but I'm not certain. Quite the pain, hah.

Comment: UPDATE AGAIN: It looks like f.lux was involved with the crashing to the login screen (the assertion failed error), as deactivating it has prevented that from happening again - and I got the error as soon as I turned it back on. I disabled Dropbox's Finder integration, and haven't had any kernel traps lately. Looking at some of the logs though, it looks like a problem with my Intel graphics DOES exist, even though the Video System Test at the Apple Store came up negative.

Comment: How do you guys know that it's a gfx issue by looking at these logs? What are `BezelServices` ?